# No settings tab in repo or deleting github repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I tried Github "series intro to github flow" where you pass simple task tests. So, now I have a repo called "series-intro-to-github-flow-myusername"

and I want to delete this, but I can't because there is no "Settings tab"

Comment: Screenshot required.

Comment: @Philippe sorry, of what?

Comment: @Philippe https://i.snipboard.io/Y8zHwt.jpg

Comment: And you're logged in as `Exp-Intro-to-GitHub-Flow-Cohort-1`?

Comment: @JimRedmond it is of github for intro course they offer